# use coretext draw string layout error

Tags: ios, core-text

my code is:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

/* Define some defaults */
float padding = 0.0f;
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef) [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12].fontName, [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12].lineHeight, NULL);

/* Get the graphics context for drawing */
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

/* Core Text Coordinate System is OSX style */
CGContextSetTextMatrix(ctx, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

//CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(padding, padding, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(padding, padding, 100, 100);


/* Create a path to draw in and add our text path */
CGMutablePathRef pathToRenderIn = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(pathToRenderIn, NULL, textRect);
NSLog(@"textRect:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.bounds));
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"hello world!"];
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute((__bridge CFMutableAttributedStringRef) attrString, CFRangeMake(0, attrString.length), kCTFontAttributeName, font);

/* Get a framesetter to draw the actual text */
CTFramesetterRef fs = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef) attrString);
CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(fs, CFRangeMake(0, attrString.length), pathToRenderIn, NULL);

/* Draw the text */
CTFrameDraw(frame, ctx);

/* Release the stuff we used */
CFRelease(frame);
CFRelease(pathToRenderIn);
CFRelease(fs);
```

}

However, that looks like this:
How can I make the text start from the top left and don't modify text frame (width = 100 and height = 100)?

```
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    x           x
    x           x
    x           x
    x           x
    x           x
    xtext...    x
    x           x
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the following in your code:

```
CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(padding, self.frame.size.height - 100, 100, 100);
```

There is no need to change the frame size of the text rect (as you required) but we need to change the frame origin's y.